# In diskpart it shows my partitions on a disk but will not select them

Tags: partitioning

I can see a star beside the partition on my USB drive but when i try to perform any operation on it, it says "No partition selected; please select a partition and then continue". I want to delete that partition and create a new one. I am trying to fix my pendrive which windows tries to format each time I put it in but says "windows did not succeed in completing the format. Please help. I donot want to recover any data. I just want to format it. Clean all command in diskpart also doesnt help.